# Erro 500 / in handle / in handle_request / required 'SEND' - Django ASGI + Gunicorn + Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a serious problem that made me lose a couple of hours and nothing solves. Below the installed modules:

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ---------
asgiref                      3.3.4
attrs                        20.3.0
autobahn                     21.3.1
Automat                      20.2.0
certifi                      2020.12.5
cffi                         1.14.5
channels                     3.0.3
chardet                      4.0.0
constantly                   15.1.0
cryptography                 3.4.7
daphne                       3.0.2
Django                       3.1.7
django-appconf               1.0.4
django-bootstrap-modal-forms 2.1.0
django-compressor            2.4
django-crispy-forms          1.11.2
django-drf-filepond          0.3.0
django-extensions            3.1.2
django-filter                2.4.0
django-mathfilters           1.0.0
django-model-utils           4.1.1
django-pandas                0.6.4
django-redis                 4.12.1
django-stdimage              5.3.0
django-storages              1.11.1
django-widget-tweaks         1.4.8
djangorestframework          3.12.4
geographiclib                1.50
geopy                        2.1.0
gunicorn                     20.1.0
hyperlink                    21.0.0
idna                         2.10
importlib-metadata           3.10.1
incremental                  21.3.0
Markdown                     3.3.4
numpy                        1.20.2
pandas                       1.2.4
Pillow                       8.2.0
pip                          21.0.1
psycopg2                     2.8.6
pyasn1                       0.4.8
pyasn1-modules               0.2.8
pycparser                    2.20
PyHamcrest                   2.0.2
pyOpenSSL                    20.0.1
python-dateutil              2.8.1
pytz                         2021.1
rcssmin                      1.0.6
redis                        3.5.3
requests                     2.25.1
rjsmin                       1.1.0
service-identity             18.1.0
setuptools                   54.1.2
shortuuid                    1.0.1
six                          1.15.0
sqlparse                     0.4.1
Twisted                      21.2.0
txaio                        21.2.1
typing-extensions            3.7.4.3
urllib3                      1.26.4
uvloop                       0.15.2
wheel                        0.36.2
zipp                         3.4.1
zope.interface               5.4.0
```

When running the server on 'python3 manage.py runserver' or 'python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000', everything is perfect! However, when running the system with gunicorn + nginx, I have the following error output:

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-04-15 15:38:31 -03; 16s ago
 Main PID: 2077 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 170.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─2077 /opt/sistema/venv/bin/python /opt/sistema/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock sistema.asgi
           ├─2080 /opt/sistema/venv/bin/python /opt/sistema/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock sistema.asgi
           ├─2081 /opt/sistema/venv/bin/python /opt/sistema/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock sistema.asgi
           └─2082 /opt/sistema/venv/bin/python /opt/sistema/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock sistema.asgi

abr 15 15:38:32 server1 gunicorn[2077]: [2021-04-15 15:38:32 -0300] [2081] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2081
abr 15 15:38:32 server1 gunicorn[2077]: [2021-04-15 15:38:32 -0300] [2082] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2082
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]: [2021-04-15 15:38:46 -0300] [2081] [ERROR] Error handling request /
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]: Traceback (most recent call last):
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]:   File "/opt/sistema/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]:   File "/opt/sistema/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]: TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
abr 15 15:38:46 server1 gunicorn[2077]:  - - [15/Apr/2021:15:38:46 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 0 "-" "-"
(venv) root@server1:/opt/sistema/sistema# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 sistema.asgi
[2021-04-15 15:39:44 -0300] [2126] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-04-15 15:39:44 -0300] [2126] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (2126)
[2021-04-15 15:39:44 -0300] [2126] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-04-15 15:39:44 -0300] [2129] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2129
^C[2021-04-15 15:39:59 -0300] [2126] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2021-04-15 15:40:00 -0300] [2129] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2129)
[2021-04-15 15:40:00 -0300] [2126] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path



BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'w(vwss5-t6@((f5umorun6@cxbf#d55@r(*t84d8_5sytd3nuf'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps', #sitemap
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_redis',
    'website',
    'accounts',
    'chat',
    'django_extensions',
    'channels',
    'compressor',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_drf_filepond',
    'stdimage',
    'bootstrap_modal_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django.contrib.postgres',  
    'django_filters',  
    'geopy',
    'mathfilters',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sistema.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "sistema.routing.application"
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sistema.wsgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer'
    }
}

#CACHES = {
#    'default': {
#        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
#        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
#        'OPTIONS': {
#            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient'
#        },
#        'KEY_PREFIX': 'django_orm'
#    }
#}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'dbsistema'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', 'psql'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS', 'senhadobancodedados'),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CHARSET': 'UTF8',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'



USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = DEBUG

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False

MEDIA_ROOT = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

DATE_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '../../../../'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '../../../../'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'

DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_UPLOAD_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_FILE_STORE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


#DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
}

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [ '%H:%M', ]


EMAIL_BACKEND = os.environ.get("EMAIL_BACKEND")
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG")


DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10000000000000
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 52428800000000


ADMIN_ENABLED = False


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.history.HistoryPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]



LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    },
}
```

asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mercati.settings')

application = get_default_application()
```

routing.py

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from chat import urls


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mercati.settings")


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            urls.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem might be? From now on, I thank you immensely.

Comment: Have you tried using previous versions of gunicorn?